# How can I withdraw a down vote?

Tags: support, down-votes

I down voted [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48956/what-is-this-red-blue-white-twinkling-star/48957?noredirect=1#comment107502_48957) because I took the bright points on the image to be stars.  It was pointed out to me that they were artifacts from an overlay of a star map.  So my down vote is invalid and I'd like to with draw it but when I try I get a message saying

> You last voted on this answer 6 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in
> unless this answer is edited.

How can I withdraw an incorrect down vote?

Answer (score 6):

In this case, I would suggest adding an edit pointing out that a star map overlay has added artifacts to the original picture.  Then you can withdraw your downvote and delete your comment(s).

Comment: Great idea, I've done that.